# Cambiar espacio de trabajo eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Estoy trabajando con un repositorio y por algun motivo la version actual se me corrompio, por lo que he decidido crear una nueva carpeta y bajarme las fuentes de nuevo.
En eclipse Juno he seleccionado cambiar el espacio de trabajo seleccionado la nueva carpeta como origen.

Lo primero que pasa es que el espacio de trabajo sale completamente en blanco y al intentar importar el proyecto me da el error:

[image: error importar proyecto]

Comment: Ya intentaste clonarlo en una nueva carpeta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema sucede cuando tienes el mismo espacio de trabajo (workspace) de Eclipse e intentas abrir dos proyectos que poseen el mismo nombre en el pom. Es decir, si revisas el pom de tus dos proyectos, encontrarás lo siguiente:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>nombre.de.paquete.principal</groupId>
  <artifactId>mi-proyecto</artifactId>
  <version>numero de version de tu proyecto</version>
</project>
```

Cuando Eclipse intenta importar un proyecto maven, lo que hace es crear un proyecto y toma como nombre el `aftifactId` indicado en el pom. Si detecta que, en el espacio de trabajo actual, existe un proyecto con el mismo nombre, arroja el error que indicas en la pregunta.

Opciones de resolver el problema:

1. Eliminar el proyecto obsoleto o antiguo de tu espacio de trabajo. Esto significa que desaparece del espacio de trabajo de Eclipse, **no es lo mismo que eliminar el proyecto físicamente**. Luego de haberlo eliminado, podrás agregar el nuevo proyecto o la nueva versión.
2. Usar un nuevo espacio de trabajo. Considera que esto usualmente significa que tendrás que instalar los plugins, cambiar las configuraciones, entre otras cosas que puede que ya tengas establecidas en tu espacio de trabajo actual.

Usa la opción que más se acomode a tus necesidades.

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias por tu repuesta, he creado un nuevo espacio de trabajo (desde cero) y tal como explicas ha funcionado correctamente.